# Cannot create Bitbucket repository in team as developer using API

Tags: api, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have a Bitbucket account named `myaccount`. I am a developer of a team named `ateam` which does not belong to me. I am not an admin of this team. Developers have their permissions set to create repositories in `ateam`. I am able to manually create a repository in `ateam` through `bitbucket` website's UI. However I am unable to do so using bitbucket's API:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:mypasswd https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ateam/rep1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"is_private": true}'    
Enter host password for user 'myaccount':
*   Trying 104.192.143.5...
* Connected to api.bitbucket.org (104.192.143.5) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.bitbucket.org
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
* Server auth using Basic with user 'myaccount'
> POST /2.0/repositories/histeam/rep2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.bitbucket.org
> Authorization: Basic YWxleGFuZHJlLW5hZGluOmJpdGJ1Y2tldDEy
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 20
> 
* upload completely sent off: 20 out of 20 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Vary: Authorization, Cookie
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 09:59:27 GMT
< X-Served-By: app-111
< X-Static-Version: 53f44cd8792e
< ETag: "2517d8a35dee8cb8cd9e5f0c889915ba"
< X-Render-Time: 0.0265378952026
< X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repository:admin
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Version: 53f44cd8792e
< X-Request-Count: 317
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 35
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.bitbucket.org left intact
{"error": {"message": "Forbidden"}}
```

I have forbidden access.

Now the owner of `ateam` made me the team's administrator. Since then I am able to create a repository in `ateam` with the very same command as above:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:mypasswd https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ateam/rep1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"is_private": true}'
```

The point is I need to create a repository using the API as a developer, not as an admin. It works using the website's GUI but not through the API: Despite having permissions to create repositories, developers are forbidden to do so using the API. So do we have a bug here? If not, am I missing something?

---

EDIT 1

Here is a screenshot of the Developer's permissions on the team. As one can see, they are supposed to be able to create a repository.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know only admins can create repos.

Comment: That is untrue, I attached an image to show you the devs' permissions on the team. Any dev can create any repository in the team using the web interface. We need to do so with the API, which is forbidden for some reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket developer here. I agree that that is a bug. And I am actually personally responsible for it :(. So, apologies for that.

I have made a fix and it will be deployed in the next deploy (probably this Tuesday).

Kind regards.

Comment: Nice thank's a lot! I'm looking forward for the fix ;)